# How to have required radio inputs using formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

Using Formtastic, I can handle required text inputs, but I can't using required radio inputs.

```
<%= semantic_form_for(current_user, html: {novalidate: false}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, :as => :text, label: false,required:true, input_html: {required:true} %>
    <%= f.input :ishuman, :as => :radio, label: false, collection: [['Yes', true],['No', false]],required:true, input_html: {required:true} %>
    <%= f.submit "save" %>
<% end %>
```

Name input is required when submitting the form but radio input does not block the form.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Its because your radio buttons will either have true or false. It cannot be empty meaning you cannot uncheck both Yes and No at the same time.

Comment: What if :ishuman is empty (null) by default ?